# Extremizing a functional subject to an equality constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem

Question at hand is:

> Let $y\in\cal C^2([0,\pi])$ satisfying $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$ and $\int_0^\pi y^2(x)dx=1$ extremize the functional 
>   $$J(y)=\int_0^\pi\left(y'(x)\right)^2dx$$

It's an MCQ, and from options using initial conditions, I could easily infer that solutions are $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{2\over\pi}\sin x$ (the other two wrong options being $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{2\over\pi}\cos x$.

But Euler-Lagrange (only method I know to find extremals of functionals) leads me to $2y''(x)=0$. What am I missing/how to solve it directly?

Comment: Euler-Lagrange works when your function space is all of $C^1([a,b])$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions (not necessarily homogeneous) and no other constraints. It is, roughly speaking, the "Lagrange multiplier equations" for Dirichlet boundary conditions. You can think about what happens when you add a constraint in Lagrange multipliers to see why it shouldn't apply as-is when you have additional constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $C^2(0,\pi)\subset L^2(0,\pi)$, we may assume that
$$ y(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \sin(nx) \tag{1}$$
holds, with the constraint $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$ given by Parseval's theorem. It also gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}y'(x)^2\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2 a_n^2\color{red}{\geq} \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^2 = 1\tag{2} $$
and equality holds iff $a_n=0$ for every $n\geq 2$, so the only extremal  functions are $\color{red}{\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(x)}$.

This is just an instance of [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions).

Comment: Thank you, there's a certain beauty about this answer! A doubt, won't $a_1^2=\frac2\pi \implies a_1=\pm\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$?

Comment: @JessePFrancis: you are right, now updating.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You have $F(x,y,y')=(y'(x))^2$ and $\int_{a}^{b}G(x,y,y')dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}y^2(x)dx=1...(*)$. Now solve this 
$$F_y+\lambda G_y-\frac{d}{dx}(F_y'+\lambda G_y')=0.$$ Once you get the $y(x)$, substitute back to $(*)$. Then you will get the result after simplification.

**Result:** Given the functional $J(y)=\int_{a}^{b}F(x,y,y')dx.$ Let the admissible curves satisfy the condition $y(a)=A$ and $y(b)=B$, $K(y)=\int_{a}^{b}G(x,y,y')dx=l$ where $K(y)$ is another functional and let $J(y)$ has extremum for $y=y(x)$ then if $y=y(x)$ is not an extremal of $K(y)$, there exists a constant $\lambda$ such that $y=y(x)$ is an extremal of the functional $\int_{a}^{b}(F+\lambda G)dx$ that is $y=y(x)$ satisfies $F_y+\lambda G_y-\frac{d}{dx}(F_y'+\lambda G_y')=0.$

Answer (score 2):

The augmented functional is

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} \left( (y' (x))^2 + \lambda y^2 (x) \right)\mathrm{d}x$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation gives us the 2nd order ODE

$$y'' (x) = \lambda \, y (x)$$

whose solution is of the form

$$y (x) = c_1 \exp (\sqrt{\lambda} \, x) + c_2 \exp (-\sqrt{\lambda} \, x)$$

The boundary condition $y (0) = 0$ gives us $c_1 + c_2 = 0$. Hence, the solution is of the form

$$y (x) = \beta \sinh (\sqrt{\lambda} \, x)$$

However, the other boundary condition is $y (\pi) = 0$. As the hyperbolic sine has only one zero, then $\lambda < 0$. Thus, the solution is of the form

$$y (x) = \beta \sin (k \, x)$$

The boundary condition $y (\pi) = 0$ gives us the integrality constraint $k \in \mathbb Z$. The equality constraint

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} y^2 (x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$$

gives us $\beta = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. Hence, the solution is

$$y (x) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sin (k \, x)$$

Evaluating the original functional,

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} (y' (x))^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = k^2$$

The functional is minimized when $k = 0$, which yields the zero solution. Though the boundary conditions are obviously satisfied, the equality constraint cannot be satisfied. Thus, the functional is minimized when $k= \pm 1$, and the minimal function is

$$y (x) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sin (x)$$